# Lua C-API: get line when error occurs during lua-function call

Tags: error-handling, lua, c-api

When I call `lua_pcall` from C++ to call a **Lua-function**, I usually do something like this:

```
 const int pcall {lua_pcall(lua_state, 1, 1, 0)};
 if (pcall == LUA_OK){      
    ...
    return true;
    // OK!
 }
 std::cerr << "Error: pcall failed. Code: ";
 std::cerr << pcall;
 std::cerr << ", '" << lua_tostring(lua_state, -1) << "'\n";
 ...
 // ERROR!
```

This is nice, but not enough to determine the exact error-*line* in my lua-code. This is my terminal output:

```
Error: pcall failed. Code: 2, 'attempt to call a nil value'
Error: pcall failed. Code: 2, 'attempt to call a boolean value'
Error: pcall failed. Code: 2, 'attempt to call a nil value'
Error: pcall failed. Code: 2, 'attempt to call a nil value'
Error: pcall failed. Code: 2, 'attempt to call a userdata value'
```

How can you retrieve more information (for example the code-line) about each error?

Comment: See [luaL_traceback](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_traceback).

Comment: Thanks, but it seems  that this function is not documented anywhere. You are more than welcome to post a little working example as an answer.

Comment: I gave a link to the manual entry. Which version of Lua are you using?

Comment: 5.3.4. Yes, I've read this entry and I just don't get it. I tried calling `luaL_traceback(lua_state, lua_state, nullptr, 1);` after the first `if(...){...}` in the post's code. This did not do anything.